# Does Samsung Galaxy S II show any indication that sms sending is complete?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms

If I send an sms from Samsung Galaxy S II, it just shows a toast message saying `Sending Message...` which disappears in a few moments. Is it possible to set it to show some kind of confirmation that the sms sending is complete? Or ss this dependent on the telephone company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the message thread in the Messages app and it should say "Sent" and the time at which it was sent.

Answer (score 1):

In the default SMS app, it leaves a time stamp at the bottom of the message. e.g 2.16PM, Oct 13.

That is how it appears on my phone (S2 aswell)

Answer (score 1):

Hey make sure you have checked your Delivery Report in the message settings option. I do have samsung galaxy s2 gt i9100 and i did the same to solve my query.

Comment: how do I open Delivery Report ?

Comment: Delivery report messages are just Notifications which you can say are just Flash messages which just disappear after you clear up your notification. And Delivery message just contains the text that the message is being Sent or Not. So theres no option to open it, but you can check through Notification Panel.